# Azure VM IP geolocation?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm creating an application which uses an API that has black-listed countries. I'm currently developing this on an Azure VM. I'm in the UK and I'm allowed access to the API here, however my VM's IP shows up as being in the States which is disallowed. I believe a European IP would work.

Is there any way around this? My VM/Cloud Service location is West Europe. I've tried configuring a reserved public IP for West Europe also but this hasn't worked. I guess my understanding of what that actually does is flawed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding seems allright. Depending on the region you choose, your Cloud Service will be physically located in different [Azure datacenters](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/). For West Europe it would be Netherlands.

The thing that is flawed is IP Geolocation. These kind of services are based on databases that can be inaccurate. Microsoft for example can register some large IP address space as US, but they can assing some of these addresses to a datacenter in Netherlands - and there is no way for the Geolocation service to know about it.

For my services that are also in West Europe, some of them are reported be in US, some in NL - and different geolocation services gives different results.